# Can I post closed-source library to Maven/JCenter/CocoaPods?

Tags: maven, cocoapods, jcenter

I want to post my closed-source library to Maven/JCenter/Cocoapods. Others can freely use the binary library, but the code is not open source.

I can build self repo to fix the problem.

But if I use the central repo,

- Maven/JCenter, don't post `source.jar`;
- CocoaPods, `source` indicates the `.zip` library, `vendored_frameworks` indicates the framework file.

Is there any problems? (like, license requirements? Any docs?)

Comment: Ever thought about a decompiler?

Comment: This is up to the service's terms and is more of a legal question than a programming one.

Comment: @ssube, right, I build private repo avoiding the  probably license problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an OSS account on Bintray, you are allowed to link your open source packages to jcenter in order to widely distribute them.
With [Bintray Enterprise](https://www.jfrog.com/bintray/bintray-enterprise/), you will be able to link your closed source packages to jcenter without adding your maven -source.jar files.

HTH,
Itamar

Comment: thx, I build private repo avoiding the probably license problem.